# Turning a java class into an executable file using command line

Tags: java, cmd, command-line, executable

Hi I have a java class as shown below but I now what to be able to call the main function and give it a textfile name to use in the command line window so my input would look like this in the command line: Main.exe TextFile.txt

The class is as shown below:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

static ArrayList<Character> letters;
static ArrayList<Integer> lettersCount;
private static boolean caseSensitive = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {
// write your code here
    letters = new ArrayList<Character>();
    lettersCount = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    loadFile(caseSensitive);

    print(lettersCount, letters);

    System.out.print("Enter: \n" +
            "'1' to make it not case sensitive\n");
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = reader.nextInt();
    reader.close();

    switch (input){
        case 1:
            caseSensitive = false;
            loadFile(caseSensitive);
            print(lettersCount, letters);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.print("There was an error with your input.\n");
            break;
    }
}

public static void loadFile(boolean caseSensitive){
    File file = new File("Text.txt");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("File does not exist.");
        return;
    }
    if (!(file.isFile() && file.canRead())) {
        System.out.println(file.getName() + " cannot be read from.");
        return;
    }
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        char current;
        while (fis.available() > 0) {
            current = (char) fis.read();
            //          System.out.print(current);
            //          System.out.print("\n");
            if(caseSensitive == false){
                current = Character.toUpperCase(current);
            }
            if(current != ' ' && current != '\n' && current != '\t' && current != '\r'){
                int index = 0;
                Boolean characterFound = false;
                for (char character: letters) {
                    if(character == current){
                        lettersCount.set(index, lettersCount.get(index) + 1);
                        characterFound = true;
                    }
                    index++;
                }
                if(characterFound == false){
                    letters.add(index, current);
                    lettersCount.add(index, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


   /* int index = 0;
    for (char character: letters) {
        System.out.print(letters.get(index));
        System.out.print(lettersCount.get(index).toString());
        System.out.print("\n");
        index++;
    }*/
}

public static void print(ArrayList<Integer> lettersCount, ArrayList<Character> letters){
    int totalLetterCount = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < lettersCount.size(); x++) {
        totalLetterCount += lettersCount.get(x);
    }
    System.out.print("Total characters: " + totalLetterCount + "\n");
    if (caseSensitive == true){
        System.out.print("Most frequently used characters: (default: case sensitive) \n");
    }
    else {
        System.out.print("Most frequently used characters: (not case sensitive) \n");
    }
    for(int numRankings = 0; numRankings < 10; numRankings++){
        int mostFreqIndex = -1;
        for (int x = 0; x < lettersCount.size(); x++) {
            if(lettersCount.get(x) > mostFreqIndex){
                mostFreqIndex = x;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(numRankings + 1 + ". " + letters.get(mostFreqIndex) + " Times used: " + lettersCount.get(mostFreqIndex) + "\n");
        letters.remove(mostFreqIndex);
        lettersCount.remove(mostFreqIndex);
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Do you really need an executable?  Or do you just need to be able to read strings from the command line?  (Hint: have you thought about what `args` means, in `public static void main(String[] args)`?)